# using .env property in bash script

Tags: bash, deployment, scripting, pm2

I have a server application that has two deployments, one for the staging environment and another for the production environment. I have two individual scripts that are responsible for starting the processes. I would like to merge `start_production.sh` and `start_staging.sh` into `start.sh` by reading the environment file.

`start_production.sh`

```
#!/bin/bash
pm2 delete production
pm2 start "npm run build && npm run start:prod" --name production --log-date-format 'DD-MM HH:mm:ss.SSS'
pm2 logs
```

Inspecting the content, the only difference between the two scripts are the process name spaces which should always correspond to the environment file. Which would make it ideal to load the `.env` property `NODE_ENV`

`.env`

```
NODE_ENV=staging
```

ultimately I want to do something like

`start.sh`

```
#!/bin/bash
ENVIRONMENT={read NODE_ENV content of .env}
pm2 delete echo $ENVIRONMENT
pm2 start "npm run build && npm run start:prod" --name echo $ENVIRONMENT --log-date-format 'DD-MM HH:mm:ss.SSS'
pm2 logs
```

It might be pretty obvious that I am an absolute novice when it comes to bash scripting, so I would like for an as concrete as possible answer.

### **SOLUTION**

I will provide a solution that is an aggregated solution based on the two current answers

`start.sh`

```
#!/bin/bash
source .env
ENVIRONMENT="$NODE_ENV"
if [ "$ENVIRONMENT" != "production" ] && [ "$ENVIRONMENT" != "staging" ]; then
    echo "improper .env NODE_ENV"
    exit
fi
pm2 delete "$ENVIRONMENT"
pm2 start "npm run build && npm run start:prod" --name "$ENVIRONMENT" --log-date-format 'DD-MM HH:mm:ss.SSS'
pm2 logs
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could `source` the `.env` file. As the format `KEY=value` is compatible with how bash does its environment variables. So in your case, `start.sh` would be

```sh
#!/bin/bash
source .env

pm2 delete echo $NODE_ENV
pm2 start "npm run build && npm run start:prod" --name $NODE_ENV --log-date-format 'DD-MM HH:mm:ss.SSS'
pm2 logs
```

Comment: it creates a process with the name `echo` instead of echoing the $NODE_ENV

Comment: If you remove the echo from the commands I will mark as answer :)

Comment: Removed the echo

Answer (score 2):

Akshit's advice on sourcing the `.env` file is good.  I noticed a couple of other issues with your shell code.

The first thing worth noting is that it is a ["best practice"](https://github.com/koalaman/shellcheck/wiki/SC2086)
to double quote your variable substitutions.

The bigger issue with your example code is extraneous `echo`s.  For instance,

```
pm2 delete echo $ENVIRONMENT
```

doesn't need the `echo` in there.  The "echo" will become part of the command being run.  It is not needed to the shell to replace the variable there.

Combining those two fixes we get

```
pm2 delete "$ENVIRONMENT"
```

which should work well.